# Solicitação de remoção de resposta (1.o de Abril)

Tags: suporte

Boa gente,

Os hábitos culturais variam com os diversos meios, cidades, países e continentes.

No **1.o de Abril** passado, mandei uma resposta contendo uma brincadeira do
*dia das mentiras*
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56570/18428
(terminada com `echo lirba 1 aid zilef | rev` )
que foi posteriormente marcada e congelada pelos moderadores (como se impunha).

Posteriormente apercebi-me que este resposta causou algum mal estar entre algumas
pessoas -- o que é coisa que não era a minha intenção.

Assim sendo:

- Quero deixar aqui um pedido de desculpas ao autor da pergunta debaixo da qual 
  pendurei a respectiva resposta (ele não se queixou mas fica na mesma o pedido)
- Um pedido de desculpas a quem esta brincadeira tenha incomodado
- Solicitar a remoção da referida brincadeira (já que eu não o posso fazer por mim)

Comment: Minha opinião: Fica tranquilo com isso e não esquente a cabeça!

Comment: Eu acho que é uma excelente resposta. Pelo bom humor, e pela qualidade da resposta. Fazendo toda a gente pensar um pouco. A resposta está bloqueada e com explicação dos moderadores. Acho que não é necessário remove-la, na minha opinião.

Comment: Ah e o próprio SOen tem assim umas respostas bloqueadas que já vi. Acho que devidamente identificada não tem mal nenhum. É uma exceção e não a regra.

Comment: O problema não é o site conter humor, e sim [mantê-lo num nível "gerenciável"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). Se a resposta fosse a única da pergunta - ou a mais bem votada - vá lá, mas sendo a última numa lista de 3, e devidamente marcada, não creio estar fazendo mal ao site. Outros podem discordar, e aí que entra minha única objeção à resposta estar bloqueada - ela não pode mais receber *feedback* [diretamente]. Mas creio ser o menor dos males, melhor deixar assim. P.S. **Finalmente** entendi o `echo lirba 1 aid zilef | rev` :P

Comment: Eu ia linkar exatamente o artigo que o @mgibsonbr indicou. Pretendo postar uma resposta com calma nos próximos dias, discutindo o assunto. Dependendo de como a discussão evoluir aqui, podemos sim apagar a resposta, mas por enquanto ela permanece no site.

Comment: Acho que aqui está toda a gente de bem com a resposta @bfavaretto